# PhoneGap dynamically load the js and css file in splash screen

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, splash-screen

For my Android+PhoneGap app I want to implement a loading div to load js and css files. Currently I am using jquery.js, jquery-ui.js and css, jquery-mobile.js and css, phonegap.js and my custom js and css files.

There is a good solution about loading this file [in here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml). But I don't have any about their consequences. For example, will the mobile-ui and and css file take effect immediately or I have to trigger some function of it, `refresh` perhaps.

Also it is possible I might add a sponsor logo by an AJAX call bottom of the splash screen.

Could you please inform me about the correct approach to this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the elements need to be refreshed, take a look at:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

and play around the updatelayout event and try to load the css dynamic.

Good luck!